# Format output of code cell with Markdown

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Output of Python code cell seems to be not processed by Markdown.

For example in Python code cell there could be something like that:

```
print "**bold**"
```

And the output is: **bold** instead of **bold**. Is there a way to make it really bold?

Comment: I Know this is an old question, but I suspect this is actually linked to the "Mode" the editor is in.  When you see **bold** your are in "edit mode". This is denoted with a green left margin. If you switch to "Command Mode" (Control + ENTER) your you should get the text formatted in bold as you want

Answer (score 52, accepted):

To get markdown formatted output, you can use the Markdown object of the display machinery. A print-like function could thus look like

```py
from IPython.display import Markdown, display
def printmd(string):
    display(Markdown(string))
printmd('**bold**')
```

Comment: I would just add the `string=''` in case someone wants to replace the `print` function by `printmd` without any problem. Sometimes it is useful to use print() just to jump a line. In this case the function would return an error.