# Is there a way to dynamically change the font color in Jupyter markdown?

Tags: python, colors, jupyter-notebook, markdown, jupyter

I am using Jupyter to create a report file of an analysis I'm doing. At the end of each analysis I'll provide a summary of how many errors/irregularities the analysis has found. I was wondering if there is a way to dynamically change the font color based on the results. e.g. let's say we have a variable called "font_color" and we have a if statement that sets the variable to "Red" if there are errors and "Black" if there is none, now in Jupyter markdown set the color as:

In code cell:

`font_color = *IF statement to define color*`

In markdown cell:

```
<font color={{font_color}}>
 - Testing
```

I'm open to suggestions and if there is a better way to dynamically change font colors.

Comment: Tagged [tag:color]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in Jupyter notebooks [you can use code to output markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32035217/8508004) as well the standout and stderr channels. And also in Jupyter notebooks [you can use HTML within the markdown to color code parts of text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19746874/8508004). Combining those, you could customize something like this for your report generation:

```
from IPython.display import Markdown, display
a = "Good"
if a == "Good":
    font_color="green"
else:
    font_color="red"
def printmd(string):
    display(Markdown(string))
printmd("Summary:")
printmd(f'**<font color={font_color}>Status for a.</font>**')
```

Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46934204/8508004) and [here](https://forums.fast.ai/t/jupyter-notebook-enhancements-tips-and-tricks/17064/5).